# Remove Header of multiple CSV Files

Tags: powershell, csv

I had the request to remove the header of multiple CSV files. But I didn´t find the right solution at first. 
Now it works for me.

So I would share the solution.

```
$FilePath = "D:\my_CSV_Files_Path"

$files = Get-Childitem $FilePath -Filter "*.csv"

foreach($f in $files){
  $csv = Get-Content $FilePath\$f
  $csv = $csv[1..($csv.count - 1)]
  $csv > $FilePath\$f
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question in the first place. SO is not a blog. If you want to present a solution you found to a problem you were facing, please make sure it conforms to the Q&A format (i.e. present the problem in form of a question, then post your solution as an answer to that question).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution, that wouldn't be tripped up by any empty files:

```
$FilePath = "D:\my_CSV_Files_Path"

$files = Get-Childitem $FilePath -Filter "*.csv"

foreach($f in $files){
  $csv = Get-Content $FilePath\$f | Select-Object -Skip 1
  if ($csv) { $csv | Out-File $FilePath\$f -Force }
}
```

This uses the `Select-Object` cmdlet to filter out the first line of the file via the `-Skip` parameter.